# How is the liturgy affected by Passover falling on a Friday night?

Tags: shabbat, passover, passover-seder-hagada

This year (2015 / 5775), the first night of Passover falls on Shabbat (Friday night).  Neither my *haggadah* nor my *siddur* give much detail explaining how to integrate the two ceremonies.  The only statement I found was that on Saturday night, Havdallah is to be combined with the kiddush for the second seder.

What other tips or guidance would be useful to know for this confluence?  Is the full Kabbalat Shabbat recited or just the abbreviated one?  I assume Maariv should be completed before the seder begins, but should one do the Shabbat kiddush at the end of Maariv like usual, or wait for the kiddush in the middle of the seder? Which wording should one use: the Shabbat kiddush or the festival kiddush?  What else am I not thinking of?

Comment: Your haggadah doesn't have sections labeled something like _On Shabbat:_? Every haggadah I have ever come across does.

Comment: @Daniel Actually my more thorough haggadot do, my more English-heavy ones do not.  I phrased it like I did both to get a good list to help people with only less thorough ones, and because depending on who my guests are, I sometimes use the mostly English ones.

Comment: Careful! An English hagadah I used years ago said, "Break the middle matzah in half. Put the bigger half away for afikoman." How can this ever be done?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few notable changes:

- The full Kabbalat Shabbat is **not** said. Nusach Ashkenaz start with *Mizmor Shir L'Yom Hashabbat* (Psalm 92). Nusach Sefarad begins with *Mizmor L'David* and does an abbreviated version of *Lecha Dodi*. Nusach HaAri begins with *Mizmor L'David*.
- The Yom Tov (Shalosh Regalim) Shmoneh Esreh is recited with the Shabbat insertions and phrasing for Pesach.
- After Shmoneh Esreh, *Vayechulu* is said, but the next section *Me'en Sheva* is **not** said on the 1st night of Pesach (this is an unusual exception). Proceed to Hallel (see below) or full Kaddish.
- Many have the custom to recite full *Hallel* in shul on the 1st two nights of Pesach. The usual blessings before and after are said also. (This is not unique to Pesach on Shabbat.)
- Kiddush is **not** recited in shul, as it is assumed that everyone will be attending a Seder which includes Kiddush.
- Your *Hagadah* will indicate where Kiddush (also the 1st cup of wine) begins on the 1st night, being Shabbat. You should also add the parenthetical words or phrases for Shabbat.
- Similarly, for the 2nd Seder which is after Shabbat, your *hagadah* will indicate the paragraph for *havdalah*. There is a blessing that should be said over a flame. To perform this, you should place two of the festival candles together to create a single flame before reciting the blessing.
- Your hagadah may also indicate in the blessing just prior to drinking the 2nd cup of wine, that there is a change in the order of one of the phrases for Sat. night (2nd Seder) whereby you say *Min hapsachim umin hazvachim* instead of the usual *Min hazvachim umin hapsachim*. However, some do not have the custom of varying the order on Saturday night.
- Remember to add the standard additions for Shabbat into your various after-food blessings.

I think I have included everything, here. Happy Pesach.

Comment: And some vary the order the year _before_ Pesach falls on Saturday night.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Where have you seen this minhag?

Comment: Torah Temima, IINM. It makes much more sense. The blessing is in future tense, after all.