# Do you drink five cups of wine when a Seder falls on Friday or Saturday?

Tags: shabbat, passover, four-cups-wine

This year the two Seders are on Friday and Saturday. My understanding (please tell me if I'm wrong) is that the normal Shabbat blessings are done before the Seder on Friday night, and the normal Havdalah blessings are done before the Seder on Saturday night.

Does this mean that one drinks five cups of wine each night? Or is the wine omitted from the Shabbat/Havdalah ceremonies, leaving just the normal four for the Seder?

(I see this somewhat answered in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56319/28527 , but that primarily says that your Haggadah will explain, but none of mine do, so I'm struggling to interpret)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both the normal Shabbat blessings (kiddush) and the Havdalah ceremonies are performed *during the seder*, along with the blessings on the first cup of wine.

For Friday Night there are extra words and phrases that are added to the blessing about the holiday that additionally speak about the holiness of Shabbat.

On Saturday night, there are two additional blessings added alongside the usual blessings, the first of which is on the fire, and the second of which is an analogue of the standard Havdalah blessing.

The text of these additions should be found alongside the text for "Kiddush" in your  haggadah, hopefully along with some instructions on what to say when. Otherwise, they should be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJqdDBrpT3AhWfoHIEHSQrCiMQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sefaria.org%2FPesach_Haggadah&usg=AOvVaw1GwWGL2Q_DPuv--hRtelx5).

Answer (score 1):

@Esther 's answer takes care of the actual question. But there are three other details to keep in mind:

- Friday night - first cup size

Because the first cup on Friday night is for Kiddush as well as the first of the 4 seder cups, many authorities are of the opinion that it needs to be larger - e.g., 3.8oz instead of 3.3oz. This is only required for the first cup, only Friday night, and only for one person making Kiddush (e.g., if one person says the Kiddush with everyone else answering Amen, only one person needs to drink the larger amount).

- Saturday night - Besamim (spices)

The spices are not used on Saturday night when it is a Yom Tov (whether first or second night of Pesach or of another Yom Tov).

- Saturday night - Havdallah candle

While fire can be *used* on Yom Tov, including lighting a candle from another flame, fire can not be extinguished. Therefore, a regular Havdallah candle is not used and instead the Yom Tov candles are brought to the table for Havdallah.

Comment: Not all use the Yom Tov candles. Some do use a small havdala candle and just let it burn down.

Comment: @DoubleAA No Halachic problem with doing that. Just a practical one. I suppose you could also use two Chanukah candles - they'll generally burn for 45 minutes or less.